# @nuxt/content pages not found in production mode

Tags: npm, markdown, nuxt.js

**Explication**

Hello, I got a problem with nuxt/content on my project when i run `npm run build && npm run start`.
You have to know, in development mode there is no problem.

When i run production mode, i can't access to my files used with nuxt/content, you can see the error which appear in my console.

[image: Picture : Problem which appear in my console in production mode]

**EDIT**

I find what is the problem, this error come from SPA (if i choose SSR, it's working). Someone have an idea to solve it ?

**Step to reproduce the problem :**

1. Create a project : `npx create-nuxt-app content-project && cd content-project` You have my configuration below.
   [image: Picture : Configuration of my project]
2. Go into the project then install nuxt/content : `npm install @nuxt/content`
3. Go into nuxt.config.js and add to "modules: []" this : '@nuxt/content' then add "content: {}"
   [image: Picture : Adding lines to nuxt.config.js]
4. Into tsconfig.json, add this lines at "types" : "@nuxt/content",
   [image: Picture : Adding line to tsconfig.json]
5. At the root of the project, add a dir named "content", into this directory create a file named "test.md" and add this lines into the file :

```
---
title: Introduction
description: Apprenez comment utiliser @nuxt/content.
---

## Liens

<nuxt-link to="/articles">Nuxt Link vers le Blog</nuxt-link>

<a href="/articles">Lien Html vers le Blog</a>

[Lien Markdown vers le Blog](/fr/articles)

<a href="https://nuxtjs.org">Lien Html externe</a>

[Lien Markdown externe](https://nuxtjs.org)
```

6. Into pages directory, create a new file named "testcontent.vue" and add this code into :

```
<template>
  <article>
    <h1>{{ page.title }}</h1>
    <nuxt-content :document="page" />
  </article>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  async asyncData({ $content }) {
    const page = await $content('test').fetch()

    return {
      page,
    }
  },
}
</script>
```

7. Now, you can save and try this in dev mode `npm run dev`, try this link "http://localhost:3000/testcontent", this should work.
8. Then try this in production mode `npm run build && npm run start`. I don't understand why that doesn't work.

Comment: Did not played with it yet, so I can only link this resource: https://nuxtjs.org/blog/creating-blog-with-nuxt-content/ Tell me if you find a way thanks to it.

Comment: @kissu this is not working. I tried to repeat her actions, in dev this is working. But at the end, when I generate my project with npm run generate (instead of nuxt generate for her) I got the same error.

Comment: What is your `npm run generate` command doing in your `package.json` ?

Comment: My ```npm run generate``` is doing ```nuxt-ts generate```

Comment: Did you followed the TS setup for this package ? This is probably the issue here, not the `@content` part. https://typescript.nuxtjs.org/guide/setup/

Comment: No but when i created my project, i selected typescript.  
I am gonna check this page when i come back to you.
Thanks

Comment: Try to make the usual JS setup first and see if it works. Never used TS with Nuxt so I cannot tell what is buggy here.

Comment: This isn't working, i have the same error. Maybe it is because my target is "server" and not "static".

Comment: It should change anything tbh. `nuxt generate` is for `static`, `nuxt build` is for `server` btw. It's **not** interoperable.

Comment: The problem was my configuration, my application is a SPA, so I have to have a static target.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved. I was using a SPA with target "server". In nuxt.config.js you have to put this line : `target: 'static',` if your application is a SPA.

"This way, Nuxt Content will know that it has to embed the database and avoid calling the server middleware." from https://github.com/nuxt/content/issues/144

Comment: You can totally use either `server` or `static` as of the `target`. It will only change the fact that you will need a NodeJS server running on the background or not. If you want an SPA only, you need to set `ssr: false`.

Comment: My ```ssr: false``` was already at false and that was not working. When i changed to static my application content worked.

Comment: What's the point of using Nuxt + content if you're going SPA only ? You will lose all the benefit of performance + SEO.

Answer (score 0):

You can totally use an SPA or even a full universal app with a `target: static`. I'm not sure that you get the linked post in your answer right.

It's clearly saying that you can get `target: static` (hence, host it on Netlify or alike) and keep the universal mode (`ssr: true (default)`), as [shown in the documentation](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/configuration-glossary/configuration-ssr). The only thing that needs to be done is to `nuxt generate` rather than `nuxt build` since you're aiming for a static build.

Also, this comment is 6+ months old, we're using Nuxt 2.15.2 as of today.

I'd still recommend going `static` + universal to get all the benefits of nuxt + it's content module.